# Modern Day Alternative to Frames?

Tags: jquery, html, frames

What is the current modern alternative to frames?

I want to build the equivilant of a two frame website, with the top frame containing elements that DO NOT RELOAD, the the bottom "frame" being the content frame, which reloads as needed.

Comment: You can reload any element you like with ajax.

Comment: Just saying: Why do you want that? If the browser does its job right, the reloading should not be a problem.

Comment: It would be for a radio website, which has a flash media player in the header.  I do not want it to reload and interrupt the stream every time a person changes pages.

Comment: Not mentioned in the answers so far, but although framesets are deprecated it is still perfectly acceptable to use iframes. In your case the top part that doesn't reload would be the main page, and the "content frame" would be the iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with AJAX.  You load content dynamically as it's needed.  Your content area need not even have size limits - as the user scrolls down the page you can load additional content automatically underneath what was already loaded.

Comment: Look at a Twitter feed page - when you scroll to the bottom, it loads more tweets.  Scroll down again and it loads more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use server-side languages like PHP and ASP.Net, but if you don't want the header to reload, then AJAX is the way to go.

Using jQuery lib:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "foo.html",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(){
        alert("Done!");
      }
});
```

Comment: what does server language have to do with client side layout?

Comment: If you have a same header on all pages you can include it in all files with PHP's include() function

Comment: Though often used with a server side language, you can always make AJAX requests to static resources.  For example, he could have 5 static .html pages that he wants to toggle through in the bottom pane.  No need for PHP for that.

Comment: Did I write that server-side language is a must? No, I didn't. I just wrote that it is a posibility

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a single page application. See Steve Sanderson's presentation and blog posts - http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/

He's using ASP.NET, but the concepts are the same for other server side technologies.