# What are the usability issues with frames?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, xhtml

Why does w3c discourage frames in xhtml?  What are the navigational issues with frames?  What are the technologies that supersede frameset and frame?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript, jQuery, CSS or Ajax?

Comment: Ever tried bookmarking something in a frame?

Comment: @BoldClock I presumed jQuery / Ajax are being used, instead of frames, to refresh part of the page while retaining header, footer and the side bar.  Please excuse my ignorance if I am off the mark.

Comment: So... what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does w3c discourage frames in xhtml?

- They break the one-uri-one-document principle.
- They break bookmarking
- They break linking to a document
- They complicate printing

> What are the technologies that supersede frameset and frame?

- Server side (or preprocessed) templates or includes.
- Ajax combined with careful use of the History API

Answer (score 0):

The "alternative to frames" part of the question is answered by

[Modern Day Alternatives to Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609977/modern-day-alternative-to-frames)